# How to tell if a emacs library is loaded?

Tags: load-path, require

Is there a function that will tell me for a given library foo if

```
(require 'foo)
```

has previously happened?

Comment: How about?  `featurep`

Comment: If you looked at the help info for `provide` it would have told you about a variable it records this in, and if you looked at the documentation for that variable it would tell you about the proper way to test it (as per @lawlist): `featurep`.

Answer (score -1):

```lisp
(member 'foo features)
```

See [elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html) about features.